# UINavigationController title pressed

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I want to know if there any option to know if the user has clicked on the UINavigationController title.
I mean, if there is a navigation controller and its titled "Hello", I want to do something if the user has pressed on the "Hello".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIGestureRecognizer for this. More specifically UITapGestureRecognizer.

Just add it to the UINavigationBar on the UINavigationController.